# Symfony2 UniqueEntity Validation and custom message

Tags: validation, symfony

I have a problem with the custom message in the `validator`.
I use embedded forms and when I save data to `DB` some embedded form has a value already exists in `DB`. When constraint prevents save I get the error 'Sprzęt o takim identyfikatorze już istnieje', but I don't know which.
It's possible display in message bad value?
I read the documentation and I found about `{{ limit }}` for `min`, `max` but I can find nothing about `UniqueEntity`.

```
AppBundle\Entity\Hardware:
  constraints:
          - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
              fields: [sn]
              message: 'Sprzęt o takim identyfikatorze już istnieje.'
              groups: [inventory]
```

Comment: Isn't the error appearing next to the field?

Comment: Can you post code of your controller action where the form is precessed?